What does "\x{01}" mean in C++?
The code below:
#include <sstream>

int main() 
{
    std::istringstream iss{"\x{01}"};
}

Compiles fine with CLang and GCC and doesn't compile with MSVC (see the demo).
What this syntax means for the first two compilers (can't find in the standard) and why it doesn't work for the recent version of MSVC?

" warning: delimited escape sequences are only valid in C++23"

@AviBerger, thank you. What is the source of the warning (I mean, have I missed it somewhere on godbolt)? And shouldn't the latest MSVC with /std:c++latest option support C+23 features?

@DamirTenishev MSVC's C++23 core language features support is rather... Limited

I went to your godbolt link and changed your -std=c++23 to -std=c++20 . If you check https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support , it is shown as not supported by MSVC, .

@AviBerger, strange. Maybe I misuse godbolt, but with the same changes demo and get it compiled with both CLang and GCC with -std=c++20. So, I am not sure for which compiler you changed the option, exactly.

@DamirTenishev Actually, I also added -pedantic, but neglected to mention it, sorry. I always try to use -Wall -Wextra -pedantic. Sort of a reflex addition.

@AviBerger, now got the same clarifications from the compilers; thank you. (They are buried a little bit deep, although.)

It is defined in [lex.ccon] as a character literal:
The following is taken from C++23 draft N4928, which looks a bit different than the current definition on eel.is:
hexadecimal-escape-sequence:
   \x hexadecimal-digit
   hexadecimal-escape-sequence hexadecimal-digit
   \x{ simple-hexadecimal-digit-sequence }

The new version (on eel.is) seems more appropriate, so this was probably a fix.
As for MSVC, it does not support this as of the day of the question (2024-10-09). Do a browser text search for the term "Delimited escape sequences".

According to the definition you quoted, \x{01}23 is also a valid hex escape, which must be an error. I can see why they changed it in the latest draft.

Thank you. So, is it a synonym (in this case) for the "\x1}"? If this is a draft so far, am I correct that this is up to compiler either to support it or not?

@DamirTenishev A compiler that supports C++23 must support this syntax.

N4950, which is the latest working draft before C++23, gives the same version as eel.is. The one you quoted is erroneous and not part of any standard.
